# Getting API data via asynch-await instead of callback

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to get via the kraken-node api ticker data.

I tried the following ways:

```
import KrakenClient from "kraken-api";
const knex = require('knex')(require('../knexfile'))
const kraken = new KrakenClient();

//*********************
//ASYNCH AWAIT EXAMPLE*
//*********************

const tickerAsynch = async function() {
    // Get Ticker Info
    return kraken.api('Ticker', { pair: 'XXBTZUSD' });
};
tickerAsynch().then(data => console.log(data)).catch(err => console.log(err))

//*****************
//CALLBACK EXAMPLE*
//*****************
// Get Ticker Info 

const tickerCallback = function() {
    kraken.api('Ticker', { "pair": 'XXBTZUSD' }, function(error, data) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
        else {
            console.log(data.result);
        }
    })
};

console.log("Callback: " + tickerCallback())
```

The `ASYNCH AWAIT EXAMPLE` just gives me the http request back:

> Callback: undefined Request {   domain: null,   _events:     { error:
>   [Function: bound ],
>        complete: [Function: bound ],
>        pipe: [Function] },   _eventsCount: 3,   _maxListeners: undefined,   method: 'POST',   headers:     { 'User-Agent': 'Kraken
>   Javascript API Client',
>        host: 'api.kraken.com',
>        'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
>        'content-length': 13 },   timeout: 5000,   callback: [Function],   readable: true,   writable: true,   explicitMethod: true,   _qs:
>   Querystring {
>        request: [Circular],
>        lib: { formats: [Object], parse: [Function], stringify: [Function] },
>        useQuerystring: undefined,
>        parseOptions: {},
>        stringifyOptions: { format: 'RFC3986' } },   _auth:     Auth {
>        request: [Circular],
>        hasAuth: false,
>        sentAuth: false,
>        bearerToken: null,
>        user: null,
>        pass: null },   _oauth: OAuth { request: [Circular], params: null },   _multipart:     Multipart {
>        request: [Circular],
>        boundary: '839beaf0-e37d-459b-a879-0d1e2b22aab4',
>        chunked: false,
>        body: null },   _redirect:     Redirect {
>        request: [Circular],
>        followRedirect: true,
>        followRedirects: true,
>        followAllRedirects: false,
>        followOriginalHttpMethod: false,
>        allowRedirect: [Function],
>        maxRedirects: 10,
>        redirects: [],
>        redirectsFollowed: 0,
>        removeRefererHeader: false },   _tunnel:     Tunnel {
>        request: [Circular],
>        proxyHeaderWhiteList: 
>         [ 'accept',
>           'accept-charset',
>           'accept-encoding',
>           'accept-language',
>           'accept-ranges',
>           'cache-control',
>           'content-encoding',
>           'content-language',
>           'content-location',
>           'content-md5',
>           'content-range',
>           'content-type',
>           'connection',
>           'date',
>           'expect',
>           'max-forwards',
>           'pragma',
>           'referer',
>           'te',
>           'user-agent',
>           'via' ],
>        proxyHeaderExclusiveList: [] },   setHeader: [Function],   hasHeader: [Function],   getHeader: [Function],   removeHeader:
>   [Function],   localAddress: undefined,   pool: {},   dests: [],
>   __isRequestRequest: true,   _callback: [Function],   uri:     Url {
>        protocol: 'https:',
>        slashes: true,
>        auth: null,
>        host: 'api.kraken.com',
>        port: 443,
>        hostname: 'api.kraken.com',
>        hash: null,
>        search: null,
>        query: null,
>        pathname: '/0/public/Ticker',
>        path: '/0/public/Ticker',
>        href: 'https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Ticker' },   proxy: null,   tunnel: true,   setHost: true,   originalCookieHeader: undefined,
>   _disableCookies: true,   *jar: undefined,   port: 443,   host: 'api.kraken.com',   body: 'pair=XXBTZUSD',   path: '/0/public/Ticker',
>   httpModule:     { Server: { [Function: Server] super*: [Object] },
>        createServer: [Function: createServer],
>        globalAgent: 
>         Agent {
>           domain: null,
>           _events: [Object],
>           _eventsCount: 1,
>           _maxListeners: undefined,
>           defaultPort: 443,
>           protocol: 'https:',
>           options: [Object],
>           requests: {},
>           sockets: {},
>           freeSockets: {},
>           keepAliveMsecs: 1000,
>           keepAlive: false,
>           maxSockets: Infinity,
>           maxFreeSockets: 256,
>           maxCachedSessions: 100,
>           *sessionCache: [Object] },
>        Agent: { [Function: Agent] super*: [Object] },
>        request: [Function: request],
>        get: [Function: get] },   agentClass:     { [Function: Agent]
>        super_: { [Function: Agent] super_: [Object], defaultMaxSockets: Infinity } },   agent:     Agent {
>        domain: null,
>        _events: { free: [Function] },
>        _eventsCount: 1,
>        _maxListeners: undefined,
>        defaultPort: 443,
>        protocol: 'https:',
>        options: { path: null },
>        requests: {},
>        sockets: {},
>        freeSockets: {},
>        keepAliveMsecs: 1000,
>        keepAlive: false,
>        maxSockets: Infinity,
>        maxFreeSockets: 256,
>        maxCachedSessions: 100,
>        _sessionCache: { map: {}, list: [] } } }

Whereas I get via the callback example the prices back:

```
{ XXBTZUSD: 
   { a: [ '4347.99900', '1', '1.000' ],
     b: [ '4345.00000', '1', '1.000' ],
     c: [ '4354.97000', '0.19747745' ],
     v: [ '74.25674323', '10944.61634833' ],
     p: [ '4391.05837', '4290.88239' ],
     t: [ 314, 31776 ],
     l: [ '4264.00000', '4082.99500' ],
     h: [ '4468.00000', '4484.29000' ],
     o: '4349.98700' } }
```

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong within my `asynch-await` example?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: Which version of kraken-api are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

I think kraken.api expects a callback and doesn't return a promise, you can always wrap a callback with a promise using the code below

```
function getKrakenPromise(){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
            kraken.api('Ticker', { "pair": 'XXBTZUSD' }, function(error, data) {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error);
                reject(error)
            }
            else {
                console.log(data.result);
                resolve(data);
            }
        })
  })
}
```

and then call getKrakenPromise() instead of the api

Comment: Just want to add that "As of version 1.0.0: All methods return a promise."

Comment: the call back works for the OP, so wrapping it with a promise should work for him